# SwiftUI textView onChange not working properly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was making a search bar with onchange in which it recieve some data for every change. But sometime when I type fast the working is not proper. I think I need to use debounce here. I've tried and fails (beginner to swift)
Here is my code :

```
struct Result: Codable{
    var searchResult :[Real]
}
struct Real: Codable{
    var _id : String
    var name : String
}
struct ContentView: View {  @State private var text: String = ""
 @State private var isEditing = false
 @State private var results = [Result]()
 @State private var real = [Real]()
 var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading){
    HStack {
    TextField("Search ...", text: $text)
    .onChange(of: text) {
          guard let url = URL(string: "https://'api link'")else{
                     print("inavlid url")
                     return
                     }
          let json: [String: Any] = ["searchKey":text]
          let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
          var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                            request.httpMethod = "POST"
                            request.httpBody = jsonData
                        
                            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){
                                data,response,error in
                                if let data = data{
                                    do {
                                        let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
                                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                           self.real = decodedResponse.searchResult
                                        }
                                        print("tommtoow")
                                     } catch let jsonError as NSError {
                                       print("JSON decode failed: \(jsonError)")
                                     }
                                     return
                                }
                                print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                            }.resume()
                        print($0)
                    }
          
                      } 
            }
            }
    } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can rectify your issues here easier when you first try splitting such a spaghetti-code into a _controller-layer_ (in your case an `ObservableObject` class could do it with the networking) and _view-layer_ (the SwiftUI part of your app with an `@ObservedObject` property of your controller) – when such that separation happens you can control the asyncronous search-flow on a way better way even using the same snippet or convert it to `Combine` and publish the result only when it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement a general API request with a method .onAppear(perform: ) and onChange can be used after to filter results

Answer (score 0):

with "onChange" you do your request every time you type something, hence your issue. What you probably want is to use "onSubmit" (ios15) or "onCommit" (will be deprecated), that way you do your request only when you are finished typing it in.

Comment: onCommit is for when user clicks the return key right? I need to give user the suggested keyword for the search bar while the user types.

Comment: yes, onCommit is for when user clicks the return key. I cannot see where you update the "text" to show the user the suggested keyword.

Comment: I have a list underneath. here is am adding the data to the list :  let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
                                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                           self.real = decodedResponse.searchResult
                                        }